# Building GLib on POWER9

Tags: gcc, glib

I tried building GLib 2.67.0 on a POWER9 machine. `meson build` failed with the following error message:

```
subprojects/libffi/src/meson.build:71:2: ERROR: Problem encountered: Unsupported pair: system "linux", cpu family "ppc64"
```

If it helps, here are some details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux tellico-master0 4.14.0-115.10.1.el7a.ppc64le #1 SMP Wed Jun 26 09:32:17 UTC 2019 ppc64le ppc64le ppc64le GNU/Linux
```

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Spack GCC) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Are there any known workarounds for this?

Comment: GLib uses the meson port of libffi maintained by the GStreamer project. File a bug against https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/meson-ports/libffi

Comment: Alright, I just filed a bug report [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/meson-ports/libffi/-/issues/3).